# Unhandled Exception: type 'List<int>' is not a subtype of type 'String' in type cast flutter http post request

Tags: flutter, http, dart, post

I'm trying to send a post request with flutter that contains a field with an array of objects, I should send a list with int ( ids) of the objects .. something like

```
List<int> theList = [10,20,30,40,50]
```

But flutter won't let me send it this way returning the error :

```
Unhandled Exception: type 'List<int>' is not a subtype of type 'String' in type cast flutter HTTP post request
```

here is my code :

```dart
  Future lawyerRegister(LawyerRegisterModel lawyerRegisterModel) async {
    String theUrl = '${baseURL}Lawyer/';

    Client client = Client();
    List<int> lawyerIDImageBytes =
        await File(lawyerRegisterModel.lawyerIDImagePath).readAsBytes();
    String lawyerIDImageBytes64Image = base64Encode(lawyerIDImageBytes);
    List<int> personalImageBytes =
        await File(lawyerRegisterModel.lawyerIDImagePath).readAsBytes();
    String personalImageBytes64Image = base64Encode(personalImageBytes);
    try {
      return client.post(theUrl, headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Token $theToken',
      }, body: {
        'sections': lawyerRegisterModel.fields, //Error comes from this line,, here is where i want to send the array of objects
        'city': lawyerRegisterModel.cityID.toString(),
        'bio': lawyerRegisterModel.bio,
        'full_name': lawyerRegisterModel.fullName,
        'mobile': lawyerRegisterModel.mobile,
        'lawyer_id': lawyerIDImageBytes64Image,
        'image': personalImageBytes64Image,
      }).then((response) {
        print(response.body);
      });
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    } finally {
      client.close();
    }
  }
```

also when I try to change the field to send it as a string

```
 'sections': lawyerRegisterModel.fields.toString(),
```

it returns this error from the backend :

```
Incorrect type. Expected pk value, received str.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can encode your POST body in JSON.

```dart
return client.post(theUrl, headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Token $theToken',
      }, body: jsonEncode({
        'sections': lawyerRegisterModel.fields, 
        'city': lawyerRegisterModel.cityID.toString(),
        'bio': lawyerRegisterModel.bio,
        'full_name': lawyerRegisterModel.fullName,
        'mobile': lawyerRegisterModel.mobile,
        'lawyer_id': lawyerIDImageBytes64Image,
        'image': personalImageBytes64Image,
      }))
```

Edit: Do note that you need to `import 'dart:convert'` for `jsonEncode`

Answer (score 0):

You can encode your List of int as String

```
import 'dart:convert';


List<int> theList = [10,20,30,40,50];
String encodedList = jsonEncode(theList);
```

Comment: Gives me "Incorrect type. Expected pk value, received str."